# Simple link hover & click event working in FF but not IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, onclick

Please check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69c2hs0x/

When the mouse hovers over a line item, an "EDIT" link appears on the right hand side of the line. In Firefox and Chromes, clicking the EDIT link successfully fires an alert box.

In Internet Explorer, however, (IE v11.0.13 here) the EDIT link appears, but does not respond to mouse clicks. I've spent hours trying to work out why, but am at a loss. The link's `href` even appears in the IE status bar, but will not respond to a single click. It does, however, respond to a double-click. Why won't a single click trigger a click event in IE?

Secondary question: Why is the `:hover` style not applied to the EDIT link in both IE and FF?

Comment: you may need to test for event targets like this `var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;` and then check `target.id === 'insertlink'` (btw, I recommend using `===` instead of `==`)

Comment: @ochi Thanks I see what you mean, however the event isn't firing in the first place, which is the main problem. Strangely it only fires on a double-click in IE, then the code runs ok. The lack of event firing on single click is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, seems the problem was with mouseover/mouseout. Changing `$(".sectionstyle").mouseover(...)` to `$(".sectionstyle").mouseenter(...)`, and similarly swapping mouseout() for mouseleave(), solves the issue.

Thanks to Reddit's /u/rbobby in /r/webdev for that one, they got to it before SO. :)